# What kind of transaction context does an injected EntityManager have in an EJB whose transaction context is TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED?

Tags: jpa, ejb

Suppose I have an EJB that is annotated with:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
```

Suppose further that it has an `EntityManager` injected into it:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
```

If I perform various operations on the `EntityManager`, will a resource-local transaction be started and committed for each such operation?  Or will there be one for all of them?  Or is this behavior undefined by the JPA specification?  I could not find a suitable paragraph either way in either the JPA 2.0 specification or the EJB 3.1 specification.

I understand that there will not be a *JTA* transaction started for the EJB method, but I am not clear on what kinds of transactions will be in effect for the underlying `EntityManager`.  I am presuming that the behavior is undefined but I'm hoping that someone from the larger StackOverflow community knows better, or has insight into this area of the specification, or into the discussions that dealt with this area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are the few excerpts from JSR 318 & section 13.6.5 might clear most of the questions.

> **13.6.2.1 NOT_SUPPORTED**
>
> The container invokes an enterprise bean method whose transaction
>   attribute is set to the NOT_SUPPORTED value with an unspecified
>   transaction context.
>
> If a client calls with a transaction context, the container suspends
>   the association of the transaction context with the current thread
>   before invoking the enterprise bean’s business method. The container
>   resumes the suspended association when the business method has
>   completed. The suspended transaction context of the client is not
>   passed to the resource managers or other enterprise bean objects that
>   are invoked from the business method.
>
> If the business method invokes other enterprise beans, the container
>   passes no transaction context with the invocation.
>
> **13.6.5 Handling of Methods that Run with “an unspecified transaction context”**
>
> The EJB specification does not prescribe how the container should
>   manage the execution of a method with an unspecified transaction
>   context—the transaction semantics are left to the container
>   implementation. Some techniques for how the container may choose to
>   implement the execution of a method with an unspecified transaction
>   context are as follows (the list is not inclusive of all possible
>   strategies):
>
> - The container may execute the method and access the underlying resource managers without a transaction context.
> - The container may treat each call of an instance to a resource manager as a single transaction (e.g. the container may set the
>     auto-commit option on a JDBC connection).
> - The container may merge multiple calls of an instance to a resource manager into a single transaction.
> - The container may merge multiple calls of an instance to multiple resource managers into a single transaction.
> - If an instance invokes methods on other enterprise beans, and the invoked methods are also designated to run with an unspecified
>     transaction context, the container may merge the resource manager
>     calls from the multiple instances into a single transaction.
> - Any combination of the above.

As mentioned above in specification section 13.6.2.1, the context interaction between the client & container is being described.

In section 13.6.5, the underlying mechanism of container for handling such transaction is being described, but it depends on the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by Nayan Wadekar, the EntityManager will have no transaction associated.

In your example you specified a transaction-scoped EntityManager (default value if not specified otherwise). This implies that methods requiring an active transaction will throw a TransactionRequiredException, like [persist](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/persistence/EntityManager.html):

```
[Throws] TransactionRequiredException - if invoked on a container-managed entity manager of type PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION and there is no transaction
```